# How to mark text as eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am developing eclipse plugin that read the user code and offer some features to the user while he writes the code. 
One of my features is to color several text in the user code like " if"  "while"  etc.
I tried to color the text with stylerange but it massed up with the eclipse original colors. So I need any information about how to color /mark in exact location in the user code. 
Thanks

Comment: Is this a new editor that you are writing or are you trying to extend an existing editor?

Comment: I am not writing new editor I am using the eclipse editor and exrends the eclipse classes

Comment: In that case you might want to look at [Eclipse XText](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/) which provides a framework for developing language editors.

Comment: Otherwise read all of the Eclipse help on [Editors](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors.htm&cp=2_0_13)

Comment: You probably didn't understand what I wanted to say,  My plugin should  mark "IF"  in the user code if the user hold his mouse on the else.  I already found the offset if this if but I don't know how to colir this "IF"

Comment: An annotation would be one way, that is covered in the Editors help.